How to Integrate AWS Cloudwatch logs with AWS Opensearch on VPC?
Our application has a scenario, where we are ingesting AWS cloudwatch logs to AWS OpenSearch which is on VPC. Now, what I want to achieve is that everytime when cloudwatch logs are generate, I want to filter them based on some condition and put into the opensearch index. I am only interested in the events timestamp, For example, let's say, a document is sent to S3 bucketA and then to S3 bucketB, then to SNS and then finally to opensearch. Now user should be able to see the timestamps of whereever the document moved like S3A, S3B, SNS and OS.
My AWS Cloudwatch logs looks like this:

Field Value @ingestionTime     1713350428424 @log
376727179254:/aws/lambda/test @logStream
2024/04/17/[$LATEST]31dd891a6b8f4398bbe3cbc56dbc2c13 @message
Datamodel has been uploaded successfully for dataset Number : 1
@timestamp     1713350421742

This is my index:
PUT /test-index
{
"mappings": {
      "properties": {
         "s3A": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "s3B": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "os": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "sns": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    },
"settings": {
"number_of_replicas": 1 ,
"number_of_shards": 2
}
}

I don't know what is the standard and the best way as I am not sure even we should have lamdbda created to pick a cloudwatch event and put into the OpenSearch index or even if this design is good enough. Help is welcomed.

I would look into creating an EventBridge Trigger for a Lambda Function. The Lambda function would receive the CloudWatch log(s) as they're created, and can be attached to your VPC then index the log in OpenSearch.
